# Nan values when using np.linspace() as input

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to calculate the probability of transmission for an electron through a series of potential wells. When looping through energy values using np.linspace() I get a return of nan for any value under 15. I understand this for values of 0 and 15, since they return a value of zero in the denominator for the k and q values. If I simply call getT(5) for example, I get a real value. However when getT(5) gets called from the loop using np.linspace(0,30,2001) then it returns nan. Shouldnt it return either nan or a value in both cases?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getT(Ein):
    #constants
    hbar=1.055e-34 #J-s
    m=9.109e-31 #mass of electron kg
    N=10 #number of cells
    a=1e-10 #meters
    b=2e-10 #meters

    #convert energy and potential to Joules
    conv_J=1.602e-19
    E_eV=Ein
    V_eV=15
    E=conv_J*E_eV
    V=conv_J*V_eV

    #calculate values for k and q
    k=(2*m*E/hbar**2)**.5
    q=(2*m*(E-V)/hbar**2)**.5

    #create M1, M2 Matrices
    M1=np.matrix([[((q+k)/(2*q))*np.exp(1j*k*b),((q-k)/(2*q))*np.exp(-1j*k*b)], \
                  [((q-k)/(2*q))*np.exp(1j*k*b),((q+k)/(2*q))*np.exp(-1j*k*b)]])
    M2=np.matrix([[((q+k)/(2*k))*np.exp(1j*q*a),((k-q)/(2*k))*np.exp(-1j*q*a)], \
                  [((k-q)/(2*k))*np.exp(1j*q*a),((q+k)/(2*k))*np.exp(-1j*q*a)]])

    #calculate M_Cell
    M_Cell=M1*M2

    #calculate M for N cells
    M=M_Cell**N

    #get items in M_Cell
    M11=M.item(0,0)
    M12=M.item(0,1)
    M21=M.item(1,0)
    M22=M.item(1,1)

    #calculate r and t values
    r=-M21/M22
    t=M11-M12*M21/M22

    #calculate final T value
    T=abs(t)**2

    return Ein,T

#create empty array for data to plot
data=[]

#Calculate T for 500 values of E in between 0 and 30 eV
for i in np.linspace(0,30,2001):
    data.append(getT(i))
data=np.transpose(data)

#generate plot
fig, (ax1)=plt.subplots(1)
ax1.set_xlim([0,30])
ax1.set_xlabel('Energy (eV)',fontsize=32)
ax1.set_ylabel('T',fontsize=32)
ax1.grid()
plt.tick_params(labelsize=32)
plt.plot(data[0],data[1],lw=6)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Because in `q=(2*m*(E-V)/hbar**2)**.5`, the difference `E-V` is negative, and Python will return NaN rather than complex numbers. That's why 15 is the tipping point: `V_eV=15`.

Comment: If you ask `linspace` for complex numbers, i.e., `np.linspace(0,30,2001,dtype=np.complex128)`, then you get only two `NaN`s.

Comment: @AhmedFasih: "Python will return NaN" - more precisely: NumPy will do so. ;)

Comment: @Falko is absolutely right, Python does the clever thing (`-1.5 ** 0.5` is fine) but the contents of the linspace are by default `numpy.float64`, and `np.float64(-1.5)**0.5` is NaN . Numpy usually wants to preserve memory formats.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Great answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference comes from the line

```
q=(2*m*(E-V)/hbar**2)**.5
```

When testing with single values between 0 and 15, you're basically taking the root of a negative number (because `E-V` is negative), which is irrational, for example:

```
(-2)**0.5
>> (8.659560562354934e-17+1.4142135623730951j)
```

But when using `np.linspace`, you take the root of a NumPy array with negative values, which results in `nan` (and a warning):

```
np.array(-2)**0.5
>> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
>> nan
```